# UITabBarItem - All items displays the selectedImage on first launch

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I have a `UITabBar` with 4 `UITabBarItems` and each item have an image and a `selectedimage`.

**Normally I want to have that :**

[image]

**But on first launch, the app displays all selected images :**

[image]

Then, if I kill the app, I have the good state (first image).
Why ?

**EDIT :**

This is a screen of my interface builder :
[image]

Comment: Please add relevant code

Comment: Or a storyboard screenshot of all items if you are setting it there.

Comment: I edited my post.

Comment: can you please share us sample project with the tabor alone we will debug and let you know the issue

Comment: are you done with the solution? or still not?

Comment: No it's not working yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.
There were this lines in the code and they make a conflict :

```
for item in tabBarController.tabBar.items! {
   item.image = item.selectedImage?.imageWithColor(tintColor: UIColor(hex: "#777777")).withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
}
```

I just deleted them and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

- First double check your selected images on your Storyboard are correct or not.
- Take a look at Image Tint color in your Tabbar and change it to white/clear color.

[image]

Comment: They are necessarily correct since they are displayed.

Comment: There isn't problem with the tint color.